# Can't get bootstrap 4 tabs to work with blade

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a little problem here, trying to design a profile but can't get bootstrap 4 tabs to work. Here's the profile page code.

```
@extends('layouts.core')
@section('content')
    <div class="content">


        <div class="row profile-content">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h2>Profile Information</h2>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Name : {{$post->name}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Email : {{$post->email}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        Verified : 
                            @if($post->email_verified_at) 
                                Yes 
                            @else 
                                No 
                            @endif
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md">
                <h2>Posted Products</h2>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" 
                            data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" 
                            aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" 
                            data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" 
                            aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" 
                            data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" 
                            aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" 
                            role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">  
                        @foreach($query as $row)
                            <div class="product-card" role="tab">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-head">
                                        <img class="card-img-top" 
                                                src="/storage/products/{{$row->image}}" 
                                                alt="Card image cap">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">
                                            <a href="/product/{{$row->unique_id}}">
                                                {{$row->name}}
                                            </a>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">{{$row->price}}$</p>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                            @if($row->stock==0)
                                                <span style="color:red;">
                                                    Not Available 
                                                </span>
                                            @else 
                                                Stock : {{$row->stock}}
                                            @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <a href="/product/{{$row->unique_id}}" 
                                            class="btn btn-primary">
                                            <i class="fas fa-info-circle mr-2"></i>
                                            Details
                                        </a>
                                        @if(Auth::user()) 
                                            @if(!$row->stock==0)
                                                <a href="/add/{{$row->unique_id}}/1" 
                                                    class="btn btn-success mr-2">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus mr-2"></i>
                                                    Add To Cart
                                                </a>
                                            @endif 
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                    @if(Auth::user()->is_admin || $row->by == Auth::user()->email)
                                        <form class='col text-center p-0' 
                                                action="{{ action('PostsController@destroy' , $row->id)}}" 
                                                onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?');" class="text-right" method="POST">
                                            <a class="btn btn-danger w-100">
                                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color:white;"></i>
                                                <input type='submit' class='none' name="_method" value="Delete">
                                            </a>
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" 
                    aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" 
                    aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="links">
                {{$query->links()}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

The javascript just appends the content from the other tabs to this current page. I dont know what's the deal. I want the first tab to display the user posts and when i will click on the second tab i want it to replace everything that's showing currently.

Comment: please attach header and footer section, so that others can understand is there any js or css issues